# Show an alert even when the app is not running

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, voip, pushkit

[image]I am doing an app in which I want the user to be notified of something even when the app is not running. Just like in the uber driver app the user is alerted to accept/Reject a ride request. Is this possible with VoIP and PushKit? Which is the best way doing it ?

Comment: U have to use notification in iOS. There are two types 1. Remote Notification 2. Local Notification look at this linkn https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

Comment: You have answered your own question, yes you should use push notifications. I guess the real question you mean to ask is what is the best way to go about push notifications?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS. Thanks much. Push notification is not the one I require. As I mentioned the requirement is just like in the Uber driver app. User can see an alert even when the app is not even running unlike the normal push notification.

Comment: You can go for Local notification, it will serve your requirement. Look at this link for Local notification https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-usernotifications-framework--cms-27250

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Thanks again. I think PushKit along with VoIP can make it . https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html.

Comment: Yes.. you can go with that. It will be PN for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with pushkit silent notification.

Once you receive push kit payload you have to schedule local notification.

You can make local notification interactive with accept / Reject ride request and do appropriate thing on tap event like API calling, SQLite etc.

**Refer below code.** I have drafted this as per VOIP calling feature, you can draft as per your requirement.

```
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {
        // Process the received push

        var arrTemp = [NSObject : AnyObject]()
        arrTemp = payload.dictionaryPayload

        let dict : Dictionary <String, AnyObject> = arrTemp["aps"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>


        if "IfUserHasLoggedInWithApp" // Check this flag then only proceed
        {                

            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == UIApplicationState.Background || UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive
            {

                if "CheckForIncomingCall" // Check this flag to know incoming call or something else
                {

                    var strTitle : String = dict["alertTitle"] as? String ?? ""
                    let strBody : String = dict["alertBody"] as? String ?? ""
                    strTitle = strTitle + "\n" + strBody

                    let notificationIncomingCall = UILocalNotification()

                    notificationIncomingCall.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
                    notificationIncomingCall.alertBody =  strTitle
                    notificationIncomingCall.alertAction = "Open"
                    notificationIncomingCall.soundName = "SoundFile.mp3"
                    notificationIncomingCall.category = dict["category"] as? String ?? ""

                    notificationIncomingCall.userInfo = "As per payload you receive"

                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notificationIncomingCall)

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //  something else
                    }

        }
    }

}
```

**Refer more things about pushkit integration and payload.**

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

[image]

Comment: Hasya Thank you.  How do we show custom UI for Local notifications . Notification content Extensions?

Comment: This is based on settings type of notification from device settings.
Accept / reject this 2 options you can utilize will all 3 types.

Comment: Can we have normal push notification along with VoIP Push in the same app? I mean do we need to keep them separately handled ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely you can have push notification within app with Voip push. Voip push related method goes to PKPushRegistryDelegate and push notification has its methods. Both can be handled easily.

Comment: Thanks much!..  B/w Should we keep seperate configurations at backend for normal push and VoIP.. My backend is configured with amazon SNS.? Right now we have normal apns token for Normal push and the VoIP token. Can we use the VoIP token for normal push ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, push notification token and VoiP push token are different. So you need to change separately at backend too.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.. Did you mean we need to keep both tokens handled ?

Comment: Yes, both tokens has to be handled separately. As a like in whatsapp or Skype there are different way for push notification and VOIP.

Comment: Can we alert user( like a call ring) until user responds or for 30 seconds? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can alert user like ring.

Comment: How do we do it when app is in background ?

Comment: Please suggest example if any. Thanks much.

Comment: You can use local notification to notify ( alert ) user with ring tone type sound file. Refer more over here https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification particulary written for VOIP based video / audio based calling app.

Comment: I wanter to keep the alert active for 30 seconds or until the user acts on the local notification. Now the local notification is fired once just like a remote notification. I want to show an alert like in the attachment in my original question and keep it for 30 seconds. Sorry if I messed things up. I went through the code in your link. But it didn't help on this. Thanks in advance..

Comment: As per screen shot attached in your question, just go to phone setting, notification, select app, there are various options to get such alert, there is nothing related to programming. Your image and 3rd image in my answer is same, when there are 2 option then it looks like your image and when there are more than 2 option, it looks like 3rd image of my answer. Hope you understand now.

Comment: Thanks much. I think i did fail to communicate the requirement .. Anyway i shall post another Q.

Comment: Got rejected for the way VoIP + PushKit is used the above way.. Anyway Apple has setup a call to discuss on the same. Waiting for them!